# Query to get totals for all rows with the same column value, with conditions for each column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to get totals for each location from @SalesTotals which contains transaction records of all sales like below. While the TotalPreTaxSales, TotalNetCheckAmount, TotalTaxAmount totals are calculated correctly, all the totals after that (containing subqueries) total up the entire table values, not just values for each location. How do I write this to get only totals per location?

```
INSERT INTO @CalcTable 
(BusinessDate,
Location, 
TotalPreTaxSales, 
TotalNetCheckAmount, 
TotalTaxAmount, 
TotalCreditCardSales,
TotalMasterCardCardSales,
TotalVisaCardSales,
TotalDiscoverCardSales,
TotalAmexCardSales,
TotalCashSales,
TotalCashReceived
)

SELECT 
@DOB, 
LocationID, 
SUM(CheckPreTaxAmount), 
SUM(NetCheckAmount), 
SUM(CheckTaxAmount), 
(SELECT SUM(NetCheckAmount) FROM @SalesTotals WHERE TenderCredit = 'MasterCard' OR Tender = 'Visa' OR 
Tender = 'Discover' OR Tender = 'AMEX'),
(SELECT SUM(NetCheckAmount) FROM @SalesTotals WHERE TenderCredit = 'MasterCard'), 
(SELECT SUM(NetCheckAmount) FROM @SalesTotals where TenderCredit = 'Visa'),
(SELECT SUM(NetCheckAmount) FROM @SalesTotals where TenderCredit = 'Discover'),
(SELECT SUM(NetCheckAmount) FROM @SalesTotals where TenderCredit = 'AMEX'),
(SELECT SUM(NetCheckAmount) FROM @SalesTotals where TenderCash = 1),
(SELECT SUM(CashReceived) FROM @SalesTotals where TenderCash = 1)
FROM @SalesTotals group by LocationId

SELECT * FROM @CalcTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is a column like `LocationId` in the table `@FinalTotals` which links to the table `@SalesTotals`.
If this is the case then you can aggregate separately on each table and join the results:

```
SELECT 
  st.DOB, st.CheckPreTaxAmount, st.NetCheckAmount, st.CheckTaxAmount,  
  ft.sum1, ft.sum2, ft.sum3, ft.sum4, ft.sum5, ft.sum6, ft.sum7
FROM (
  @DOB DOB, 
  LocationID, 
  SUM(CheckPreTaxAmount) CheckPreTaxAmount, 
  SUM(NetCheckAmount) NetCheckAmount, 
  SUM(CheckTaxAmount) CheckTaxAmount, 
  FROM @SalesTotals 
  GROUP BY LocationId
) st LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT LocationId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TenderCredit = 'MasterCard' OR Tender IN ('Visa', 'Discover', 'AMEX') THEN NetCheckAmount ELSE 0 END) sum1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TenderCredit = 'MasterCard' THEN NetCheckAmount ELSE 0 END) sum2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TenderCredit = 'Visa' THEN NetCheckAmount ELSE 0 END) sum3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TenderCredit = 'Discover' THEN NetCheckAmount ELSE 0 END) sum4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TenderCredit = 'AMEX' THEN NetCheckAmount ELSE 0 END) sum5,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TenderCash = 1 THEN NetCheckAmount ELSE 0 END) sum6,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TenderCash = 1 THEN CashReceived ELSE 0 END) sum7
  FROM @FinalTotals
  GROUP BY LocationId
) ft
ON ft.LocationId = st.LocationId
```